# Days between two dates

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

How I can get number of days between 2 dates using **PHP**?
eg:

```
25\02\2011
25\03\2011
```

I want to make **PHP** calculation: how many days are between `25\02\2011` and `25\03\2011`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
echo date_diff(new DateTime('2011-02-25'), 
    new DateTime('2011-03-25'))->format('%a');
```

This is an Object Oriented approach, that is much more reliable and simple than some of the alternatives (using the differences in the unix timestamp, which works in **most** cases).

date_diff is an alias of DateTime::diff, so we're creating two DateTime objects and using date_diff to return a DateInterval object.

The `->format('%a')` is just asking for the interval using the total number of days. You can make it more informative with a longer format to print: `x years, x months, x days`

Comment: can please tell me what that meaning ...and pleas no oop

Comment: I've expanded my answer, why would you not want OOP? Its a much tidier approach.

Comment: oky it equal 6015.........what that mean?

Comment: running that code should echo 28. The number of days between the two dates.