# Full Days between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, date

I have dates stored in my MySQL table as yyyy-mm-dd (or typical MySQL 'date' format). How can I find out how many full days are left until then?

Like, for example, if I had:

```
2011-03-05
```

It would say:

```
17 More Days
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010946/days-between-two-dates/5010969#5010969 it uses PHP 5.3 and OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$days = (strtotime($date) - time()) / 86400;
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT
    ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) / 86400) AS days
FROM table;
```

Or as @coreyward stated (in MySQL):

```
SELECT
     DATEDIFF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,NOW()) AS days
FROM table;
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring the built-in `date_diff` method? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: @coreyward: I think the question is "why aren't you?", but if you must know: **A)** `date_diff` is only available on PHP 5.3+. **B)** because if correlates directly to the MySQL example and I don't know which solution the OP is looking for. **C)** for day and lower resolutions `date_diff` brings no added value whatsoever.

Comment: MySQL ≠ PHP. There's a method in MySQL to do what you're hacking together. It's called `date_diff` and I linked to it in my comment, and it's used in the answer to the MySQL-related question I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @coreyward: Sorry, I though you meant the PHP one. In MySQL it's `DATEDIFF` (no underscore), I forgot about it and I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5 - Date DIFF

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

You need:
(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

If not you can use this function:

```
<?php
$today = strtotime("2011-02-03 00:00:00");
$myBirthDate = strtotime("1964-10-30 00:00:00");
printf("I'm %d days old.", round(abs($today-$myBirthDate)/60/60/24));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these nearly identical questions:

PHP:
[How to count days between two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653882/how-to-count-days-between-two-dates-in-php)

MySQL:
[How to get the number of days of difference between two dates on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql)

Comment: The accepted answer in the PHP example is ugly. I prefer my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010946/days-between-two-dates/5010969#5010969 People need to use the OOP more.

Comment: And the highest voted answer on the same question is the same basic thing as you had. Six of one, half-a-dozen of another…