# how i can know how many days between 2 date by php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to count days between two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653882/how-to-count-days-between-two-dates-in-php)
>   [Full Days between two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023735/full-days-between-two-dates-in-php)

how i can know how many days between 2 date 
ex:
i want know how many days between 12\02\2011 and 15\03\2011

please help me

Comment: Use Stack Overflow's search box?

Comment: Not really relevant, but: you are using backslashes instead of slashes. This is not a date: 12\02\2011. This is: 12/02/2011. This is even better: 2011-12-31 (international format). Thought I’d mention it because this could be the source of your frustrations (and because it irked me).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2011-02-12');
$datetime2 = date_create('2012-03-15');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

You dates just have to be of one of the following formats:
[PHP Date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

look at the example. it gives you pretty much exactly what you asked.